# Why $||(T-\lambda I)^*v||=||(T^*-\bar{\lambda}I)v||$ where $T$ is normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjoint-operators

I was reading Sheldon Axler. In the proof of

> Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ is normal and $v\in V$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $v$ is also and eigenvector of $T^*$ with eigenvalue $\bar{\lambda}$ where $T^*$  is the adjoint of $T$ and $T$ is normal operator that is $TT^*=T^*T$.

there is this line that $$0=||(T-\lambda I)v||=||(T-\lambda I)^*v||=||(T^*-\bar{\lambda}I)v||$$

How we are getting this $||(T-\lambda I)^*v||=||(T^*-\bar{\lambda}I)v||$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply using the following properties of the adjoint: $$(A+B)^* = A^* + B^* \tag{1}$$
$$(\lambda A)^* = \overline{\lambda} A^* \tag{2}$$
Can you prove them?

*Edit.* Proof of $(2)$:
$$\langle x, (\lambda A)^* y\rangle = \langle \lambda Ax,y\rangle = \lambda \langle Ax,y\rangle = \lambda \langle x, A^*y\rangle = \langle x, \overline{\lambda} A^* y\rangle$$
for all $x,y\in \mathcal H$, where $\mathcal H$ is the Hilbert space you're working with.

Comment: 1st one yeah..second one not sure

Comment: @SohamChatterjee See my edit.